# Wagtail: Add support for other image file formats

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using Wagtail as a simple image library, and have the requirement to support TIFF and BMP. I dug around the source code of Wagtail, and  [AbstractImage](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/7d8a1a0d1e37f0f8c614cba55bbdb7befee12d07/wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py#L67), [WagtailImageField](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c6666c6de5e83bf94d18324858c121e6584ba47d/wagtail/wagtailimages/fields.py#L16) and [Filter](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/7d8a1a0d1e37f0f8c614cba55bbdb7befee12d07/wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py#L338) all seem interesting. It feels like it should be possible, but so far failed to get it working without altering Wagtail itself. Has anybody succeeded in adding support for another image file format?

I realize I could do my own conversion upon upload, but would much rather keep the originals managed by Wagtail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, Wagtail relies on Willow to provide a common API, which *then* talks to Pillow, Wand and other python libraries for editing images.

So it's likely you'll need to make changes to Willow first, rather than directly to Wagtail.

This is was I learned when looking into adding rotation support to Wagtail - there's an open pull request on Willow from a few weeks back here:

https://github.com/wagtail/Willow/pull/52

Once that was in, I was expecting to then need to make a PR, to Wagtail myself, to add the UI.

I've shared some notes that might be help here too, where I tried to work out how images are saved, with some links to the the docs and discussion on the mailing lists. Hope that helps:

https://workflowy.com/s/FVge.PpETxYqp6D

Comment: Thanks. Marking as correct because this was very close to the truth. I made a PR to Willow to add TIFF support (it mostly supports BMP already): https://github.com/wagtail/Willow/pull/54. And my changes to add support for both to Wagtail are here: https://github.com/maikhoepfel/wagtail/commits/bmp-tiff-support

Answer (score 0):

wagtail relies on pillow https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0

for image manipulation.
read the doc there, especially system dependencies for gif, jpeg ...

Comment: I appreciate that the underlying libraries support it. The problem is more to get Wagtail to accept different image formats (e.g. in upload), and to let it know how to handle them when displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Checking Wagtail source-code, I found that it's not possible to add more supported image types like `.avif`. Only images supported by Pillow are allowed. I think maybe there are features of Wagtail that load the image using Pillow?!

[image]